# accurate method of determining turns ratio of single phase transfomer

Tags: transformer

In determining the turns ratio of a single phase transfomer ,we are asked to use voltage ratio (Vp,Vs) side by side current ratio(Ip,Is). we open circuited the secondary transformer and put test volatge on the primary one, then we determined turns ratio a1=Vp/Vs,    similiarly we short circuited the secondary one and determined a2=Is/Ip , but when comparing with standard data we found volatge method , a1 more accurate while a2 was not that accurate and every time the same thing happens!

my question is why  voltage method is giving more accurate result, whats wrong with the current one? whats the underlying reason behind it?

Comment: What were the numbers you got for side-by-side tests? How did you know that the voltage testing method produced more accurate results? What was your reference value that you assumed to be perfectly accurate and true?

Comment: In addition to what @Andyaka is asking, have you thought about the possible sources of error during each of your measurements? Do you have any ideas on why one might be more accurate than the other?

Comment: Are your transformer windings superconductive, or do they have resistance? How did you assumed the transformer to behave when drawing a circuit model for it?

Comment: Need more details. What is the rating of the transformer (volts and current)? What voltage and frequency did you use for the test? What currents did you measure for the shorted test?

Comment: @Andy aka, yep, we got those values in ur lab exp, standard value was 2 (240/120), we got 1.97,1.98,1.99,1.199 for voltage test, but 1.65, 1.68,1.70,1.71 for current test, and my report asks for why there is the discripancy!

Comment: @JohnD we didnt have any error, i think when the current starts to flow there is some kind of loss or something , because in open circuit test there is zero current in the secondary and a tiny or almost no current the primary coil ,

Comment: @Mattman944 KVA rating 300 VA, 50Hz, volatge rating 240V/120V, current rating 1.25A/2.5A

Comment: @AlzenoDoe So there's no error, but "when the current starts to flow there is some kind of loss".  What kind of loss? Why would that NOT be considered a source of error when measuring turns ratio by measuring the ratio of currents?